# Revert one patch of git rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I'm in the middle of one big rebase with a lot of conflict.

just found out a couple of `git rebase --continue` before actual I accidentally delete one file instead of another.

How can I go back in pacth and fix this, and then reapply the patch?

Edit: `--abort`  is not a solution as I will have to do ALL the patch again. I want to abort only part of them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything in your repo stays there until git sees it's been wholly unreachable, through any ref, for at least a month<sup>1</sup>.

So you've done some equivalent of `git rebase master topic`, with say 26 commits A-Z on topic since the branch, and you did what turns out to be a really bad oops rebasing O and didn't really get the full effect until S:

```
     A...O...Z        topic
    /
...b....*             master
         \
          A2..O2..S2  the inflight rebase with the mistake in the rebased O, O2
```

Your backout is

```
git tag restart O2~
git rebase --abort
git rebase --onto restart O^ topic
```

and now you only have to redo the commits infected by the oops.

If there are good parts to the commits in the O2~..S2 series, conflict resolutions you want to retrieve, you can tag S2 as well, and then during your redo just check out the good parts from those commits, `git checkout -p boneyard~3 -- goodpart1 goodpart2 etc etc` (where you've tagged S2 as "boneyard" and the good parts are in P2)

I've done this, hosed a rebase and had to redo it. I wouldn't be surprised if everyone's done that at one point or another.  It's no big deal, even for seemingly horrendous cases like yours.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>You can force the truncation earlier. Don't Do That.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
git rebase --abort
```

This will abort the rebase and bring your `HEAD` back to the state it was before the rebase.

I don't think there is an option to revert a single patch using `git rebase`. See the possible options in git rebase docs.

```
git rebase --help
```

> ```
> GIT-REBASE(1)                     Git Manual                     GIT-REBASE(1)
>
> NAME
>        git-rebase - Forward-port local commits to the updated upstream head
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        git rebase [-i | --interactive] [options] [--onto <newbase>]
>                [<upstream>] [<branch>]
>        git rebase [-i | --interactive] [options] --onto <newbase>
>                --root [<branch>]
>        git rebase --continue | --skip | --abort
>
>    In case of conflict, git rebase will stop at the first problematic
>    commit and leave conflict markers in the tree. You can use git diff to
>    locate the markers (<<<<<<) and make edits to resolve the conflict. For
>    each file you edit, you need to tell git that the conflict has been
>    resolved, typically this would be done with
>
>        git add <filename>
>
>    After resolving the conflict manually and updating the index with the
>    desired resolution, you can continue the rebasing process with
>
>        git rebase --continue
>
>    Alternatively, you can undo the git rebase with
>
>        git rebase --abort
> ```

Also check this link if it helps.

http://arigrant.com/blog/2014/5/4/git-rebase-stepping-forward-and-back

Comment: Updated question, abort is not a solution

Comment: Updated the ans. Also check this link if it helps. http://arigrant.com/blog/2014/5/4/git-rebase-stepping-forward-and-back

Comment: That link seems the correct answer, thank you, but it is not clear what happen if after a step back, the continue make you still step forward

Comment: Updated the ans with the link in the ans. Also, i haven't tried using the approach given in the link. Try if that helps. Cut another branch from the branch you are rebasing onto. Then apply this procedure to ensure nothing bad happens to your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase --abort` and redo the rebase.

Comment: Updated question, abort is not a solution